# Accessing MSM install without a domain/subdomain

Tags: multi-site-manager, server, subdomain, ip

We're developing the site on a test URL (server IP). Is it possible to access the the MSM site without setting it up as a sub-domain or domain - ie. is there a path I can use while it's in development?

e.g. 000.000.000.000/index.php/msm-site-two/

Hoping it's obvious, it's been a very long day and I've just installed it all... (copied relevant templates/channels...)

Ta.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create subfolder **msm-site-two** and put inside index.php with

```
$assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'msm-site-two';
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://000.000.000.000/msm-site-two/';
```

and your second site will be available by url 000.000.000.000/msm-site-two/

Comment: Thanks, I had that set up correctly - I'm assuming it's an .htaccess thing (we are using default settings). I would Imagine I need to do some redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Max it led me to a couple of things

On my server I needed to set the config paths in index.php like this:

```
$system_path = '../my_system/';
$assign_to_config['site_name'] = 'msm-site-two';
$assign_to_config['site_url']  = 'http://000.000.000.000/msm-site-two/';
```

**AND** *(this where I was going wrong and there's little in the docs, even though it's obvious:)*

In the MSM site's Cpanel General Configuration:

```
URL to the root directory of your site: http://000.000.000.000/msm-site-two/index.php/
```

**The trailing slashes were important for me. I guess that might be a server thing.**